What are commutative perfect integral domains?
Let R be a commutative ring. The ring R is called perfect if every flat module is projective, or equivalently, if every R-module admits a projective cover. An integral domain is a commutative ring with no nonzero zero divisors. Is the following statement true: A perfect integral domain is necessarily a field?

What do you think? Please tell us what rings you've considered, whether you think this should be true or not, etc.

A great place to start would be thinking up some examples of flat modules.  If you can't think of any flat modules of your domain, then the assumption that these elusive modules are projective is not going to help you.

There's another important characterization of perfect rings afforded by Bass's "Theorem P":

$R$ is right perfect iff it satisfies the descending chain condition on left principal ideals.

Using this, one can easily show that a commutative integral domain that is perfect must be a field. I leave that to you.

Another property that right perfect rings have is that each nonzero submodule of a left module contains a simple submodule.  This fact accomplishes the same thing.

Also, we could note that a domain (commutative or not) that is perfect on one side or the other is necessarily a division ring.
